# Different type of indexings on same field of a document in DocumentDb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection where the documents have different kind of properties like Strings, Numbers, DateTimes.

And the indexing policy I have is like following:

```
  {
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": []
}
```

Now what I want, is to adding Range type indexing on the String fields as well.
So I edited my indexing policy like:

```
 {
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Hash",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 3
        },
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 20
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": []
}
```

But it did not work :(

I know multiple type indexing can be added on a field. Can anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: ``it did not work `` do you want to do range queries or Order By queries? could you tell us what did not work?

Comment: I needed to do the order by, that's why I added the Range type index on the Strings. But this one even not validated by the azure server. When I submit this as the indexing policy, it shows error. @FredHan-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

For a given data type, you can have only one index type (Hash or Range) for a specified path. Also Range is a superset of Hash in terms of queries that are supported. Hash supports only equality queries, but Range supports equality, range, and order by queries.

So you just need to remove the JSON block for Hash on String, e.g. like the following and the indexing policy update will succeed:

```
 {
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": 20
        }
      ]
    }
 ],
  "excludedPaths": []
}
```

Comment: I know it works. But the problem is: with the equality in Range indexing is not faster like the Hash indexing. That's the reason why I was trying to add both Range and Hash type indexing.

Comment: The problem with Range, is that ARRAY_CONTAINS no longer uses the index! Have you found a workaround for that?